# Naming flags, best practices

Tags: command-line-arguments, flags

When naming command-line flags, and flags in general what's the best practice regarding flags that disable things?

Should I be going for something like:

```
--disable-thinging
```

or

```
--no-thinging
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it `--thinging 0` and `--thinging 1` (or with `false/true`). Just like a boolean variable. You can document the default value.